# Calling delegate for Acumatica Event with the _ event notation

Tags: acumatica

Previously, in order to inject code in the middle of an event handler, you could use the code:

```
protected virtual void Customer_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
{
    // run before the base event 
    del?.Invoke(cache, e);
    // run after the base event 
}
```

With the new event style:

```
protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<Customer> e)
```

What is the proper way to call the delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an example in the code provided in the extension library for APInvoiceEntryExt.cs. The following code is how you would accomplish this:

```
protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<Customer> e, PXRowSelected del)
{
    // run before the base event 
    del?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
    // run after the base event     
}
```